# Maximum Callstack Exceeded Error when deleting Child node in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am using Angular with Angular fire to connect to my firebase realtime database. The structure of the realtime database looks like this:

```
-requests
|-openRequests
 |-{RequestId}
 |-...
|-acceptedRequests
 |-{RequestId}
 |-...
```

Now when a user accepts an request I want to move a entry from openRequests to accepted Requests. I do this in the following service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { AuthService } from '../../shared/services/auth.service';
import { Subscription, take } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RequestsService {
  newRequestAvailable: boolean = true;
  openRequestsSubscription: Subscription | undefined;

  constructor(
    private rtdb: AngularFireDatabase,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.subscribeToOpenRequests();
  }

  acceptRequest() {
    //this.unsubscribeFromOpenRequests();
    this.rtdb
      .list('/requests/openRequests')
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((data) => {
        if (data.length === 0) {
          console.log('no open requests');
          return;
        }

        const request = data.reduce((prev: any, current: any) =>
          prev.timestamp < current.timestamp ? prev : current
        );

        request.status = 'accepted';
        request.stylistUId = this.authService.userData.uid;
        request.stylistName = this.authService.userData.displayName;

        this.rtdb
          .list('/requests/openRequests')
          .remove(request.userUId)
          .then(() => {
            this.rtdb.list('/requests/acceptedRequests').push(request);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error while accepting request', error);
          });
      });

    this.router.navigate(['answer']);
  }

  subscribeToOpenRequests() {
    this.openRequestsSubscription = this.rtdb
      .list('/requests/openRequests')
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe((data) => {
        //Error still persists even when I am doing nothing in here
        /*if (data.length > 0) {
          this.newRequestAvailable = true;
        } else {
          this.newRequestAvailable = false;
        }*/
      });
  }

  unsubscribeFromOpenRequests() {
    if (this.openRequestsSubscription) {
      this.openRequestsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem now is that when calling the "acceptRequest" function I always get a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" Error.
I know that this means I have an infinite recursive loop in my code. But I really can't find where exactly. The problem partially resolves itself when calling `unsubscribeFromOpenRequests()` before executing the `acceptRequest()` function. However, the error then appears when a new entry is added to the `openRequests` node.

Does anyone have an Idea where the recursive loop might occur? Or is there a better way to implement this functionality?
Thanks!